# How do you sort numeric values stored in a hashmap then in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList`.

Each element is a `HashMap` lookup for my values.

1 of the values is numeric.

I'm using `Collections.sort()` for alpha sorting.  But the numbers are getting alpha sorted, instead of numeric sorted.

```
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myAccountList;

String Name = myAccountList.get(i).get("accountName");
Double balance = Double.valueOf(myAccountList.get("accountBalance"));  //is a number stored as a string
```

So I have the sort working on accountName just fine.

```
Collections.sort(myAccountList, new Comparator(){
   public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
      HashMap<String,String> old1 = (HashMap<String, String>) o1;
      HashMap<String,String> old2 = (HashMap<String, String>) o2;
      return old1.get("accountName").compareToIgnoreCase(old2.get("accountName"));
   }
});
```

How would I sort the field accountBalance as a number?  I doubt it matters, but I'm programming an Android app.

Comment: Why not store balances as a `Double` instead? For example, `HashMap<String, Double>`

Comment: OK, I can do that.  But what would the sort look like?  And how do I get the HashMap to accept <String, String> as well as <String, Double> ??

Comment: You can't do that if you're holding strings as well as doubles in the map.  You could however use a `HashMap<String, Object>`.

Comment: @DonRoby is right. Don't use a `HashMap` at all - see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using a `HashMap` where you should design your own class:

```
public class Account {

   public final String name;
   public final Double balance;

   public Account(String name, Double balance) {
      this.name = name;
      this.balance = balance;
   }
}
```

<sup>(Note: currently this class is [immutable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29). To make it mutable, change the fields from `public final` to `private` and add getters/setters)</sup>

Then you can store them in a `List<Account>` and sort accordingly:

```
//sort by name
Collections.sort(myAccountList, new Comparator<Account>(){
   public int compare(Account acc1, Account acc2) {
      return acc1.name.compareTo(acc2.name);
   }
});

//sort by balance
Collections.sort(myAccountList, new Comparator<Account>(){
   public int compare(Account acc1, Account acc2) {
      return acc1.balance.compareTo(acc2.balance);
   }
});
```

Note the use of a `Comparator` with the generic type parameter `<Account>`, so you don't have to cast the `compareTo()` arguments from `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do something like this:

```
Double.valueOf(old1.get("accountBalance")).compareTo(Double.valueOf(old2.get("accountBalance")));
```

To sort by both the account name and balance, you would check if the first compare is 0 (they are equal) and if so, return the accountBalance compare, assuming you are sorting by account name first.